# Blank activity option is not visible in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

Whenever I create a new project in android studio and try to add activity , I am unable to find blank activity option that is there is no blank activity option and other options such as empty and basic activity are present.
How to get  blank activity option. I have android studio 2.1.2 installed.